# Is there a way to use standard-version just to update the change log

Tags: npm-scripts, changelog

I like standard-version as it updates the changelog using git commits but for a project I'm working on versioning is managed by another command - and HAS to stay like this. Is there a way of just getting standard-version just to generate the new change log from commits (following commitlint standards) and not bump the version or create tags?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you would like Standard Version to only update the changelog and do nothing else, then you can use the skip options provided in either the CLI or the package.json file to skip all the other lifecycle steps.

#### CLI

`npx standard-version --skip.bump --skip.commit --skip.tag`

#### package.json

```
{
  "standard-version": {
    "skip": {
      "bump": true,
      "commit": true,
      "tag": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your other system only determines the new tag, but don't automatically create it for you, you can just skip bump as in the accepted answer and still get the heavy lifting from standard version with an [imperative release](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version#release-as-a-target-type-imperatively-npm-version-like) like this:

```
npm run release -- --release-as 1.1.0
```

or

```
npx standard-version -- --release-as 1.1.0
```